# DC.js + Crossfilter set up active item of the chart after manual filter

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

I have a simple DC.js bar charts with crossfilter -http://jsfiddle.net/feLuyb9b/1/

I needed to filter it by default 'Brooklyn', for example.
I do it with the `neighborhoodDimension.filter('Brooklyn');` The question is how to select by default item 'Brooklyn' for this chart after filtering?

I will be glad for any help with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using dc.js, just remove your filter on the Crossfilter dimension and filter on the chart instead:

```
rowChart.filter("Brooklyn")
```

dc.js will handle applying the necessary Crossfilter filters and updating your charts.

Comment: Here's [the docs](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.baseMixin.html#filter). You'll probably want to follow this with `chart.redrawGroup()` to update the chart and related charts.